# Scale html to be proportinally resized per screen resolution

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash, scale

I have a one page game which i created with html.

I converted flash game to html(simple html tags, not canvas). You can see the flash game link [here](https://games.eurocazino.com/games/play.php?game=grandspin)

I need to have the layout always fitting in one screen. If you resize the flash version you will see what i mean. Currently you can check my code [here](http://grandspinv2.ipoint.com.mt/).

I tried to do it with css zoom property but that is endless work for every pixel of resolutions.

ANy idea what is the best way to acheive proportinal scaling widthwise/heightwise?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

put it in a `<div style="width: 100%;height:100%;"> code you want to embed here </div>`

to answer your followup question:

```
<div style="width: 100%;height:100%;">
  <div style="width: 30%;height:30%;">
 something else to resize
  <div>
</div>
```

this way everything will be 100% of the screen in the 100% div and 30% of the size in the 30% div.

Comment: Yes but what about the rest stuff? How the rest will be scaled prportionally @8487?

Comment: everything between the div will be scaled to the screen size you can put another div inside it to size an other part to lets say 30% of 100% of the screen:
'<div style="width: 100%;height:100%;">
<div style="width: 30%;height:30%;">
 code of the game embed
</div>
 </div>'

Comment: This will not be an endless job and make me check every pixel if the content fits to its size with percentage @8487? Also how you see in the link the layout is not fullwidth, it has spaces from left and right

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is called responsive web design (you can google that)

basically what you do is make media queries and change the css based on the screen size

example:

```
@media (max-width: 625px) {

your code here

}
```

what this will do is execute the css only if the screen is smaller than 625px

Comment: I know about that but the issue currently i have is related to fitting everything properly in one screen widthwise/heightwise